# C# - how to test extension methods?

Tags: c#, mstest

I have created this C# extension method for a `Person` class:

```
public static class PersonExtensions {
    public static void Rename(this Person person, String newName) {
        person.Name = newName;
    }
}
```

How would I unit test this method? I have tried it, but the `Rename` method is not available from the `PersonAccessor` object.

Error was "the private-accessor for Rename was not found"

When I try PersonExtensions_Accessor.Rename(somePerson, newName), it says "there are some invalid arguments"

Comment: Is the extension method stored in a namespace you aren't referencing?

Comment: Is the `PersonAccessor` class in a different namespace? If so, you'll need to `using` the namespace that contains `PersonExtensions`

Comment: As with any extension method, you can access the method like any static method because that's what it really is. You should be able to do something like `PersonExtensions.Rename(myPersonInstance, myNewName)`.

Comment: What is the compiler error that you see when you try to spell out person.Rename("");

Comment: PersonExtensions.Rename( pers, "some" );

Comment: After the invalid arguments error, there is always another error message that explains what's wrong with the arguments.  What is it, exactly?

Comment: What does your call-site looks like?

Comment: Is the test in the same assembly as the production code?

Comment: @GregC: It just says: "the best match for PersonExtensions_Accessor.Rename(Person, string) has invalid arguments". The test was generated using VS2010, and the test code resides in a dedicated test project.

Answer (score 18):

Extension methods are just syntactic sugar for a different way to reference the static method.  Just call `PersonExtensions.Rename(...)` in your unit test.

Comment: The method extends `Person`, not `PersonExtensions`.

Comment: It would defeat the purpose of creating an extension method if you don't use the class that is being extended. The test would be more accurate if it called `new Person(...).Rename(newName)`

Comment: It says: "the private-accessor for Rename was not found". What does that mean?
When I try `PersonExtensions_Accessor.Rename(somePerson, newName)`, it says "there are some invalid arguments".

Comment: What is `PersonExtensions_Accessor`?  Is it supposed to have the static methods in `PersonExtensions`?

Comment: @ean5533: You can call it either `personObject.Rename("new name");` or `PersonExtensions.Rename(personObject, "new name");`. Both are valid.

Comment: @TimS. I have no idea what `PersonExtensions_Accessor` is. I cannot access `PersonExtensions` directly, which is why I have to use the accessor.

Comment: What type is it in your code?  Is it a class, an instance of a class, an instance of `dynamic`, etc.?

Comment: If PersonExtensions is public, why can't you access it?

Answer (score 6):

I think that a good approach could be testing directly the extension method in an instance of `Person`.

Taking into account the method you have implemented, a sample code would be something like this:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using PersonExtension; // Don't forget about reference it

namespace UnitTest {
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest {
        Person person;
        [TestInitialize]
        public void Init() {
            person = new Person("Person name");
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestRename() {
            Assert.AreEqual("Person name", person.Name);
            person.Rename("New name");
            Assert.AreEqual("New name", person.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Remember to reference both `Person` and `PersonExtension` classes and to have the correct hidden levels in the utility class in order to can access its methods

Answer (score 1):

Here's my production code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
   public class Person
   {
      public string Name { get; set; }
   }

   public static class PersonExtensions
   {
      public static void Rename(this Person person, String newName)
      {
         person.Name = newName;
      }
   }
}
```

Here's the edited version of generated test:

```
using ClassLibrary1;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;

namespace TestProject1
{


    /// <summary>
    ///This is a test class for PersonExtensionsTest and is intended
    ///to contain all PersonExtensionsTest Unit Tests
    ///</summary>
   [TestClass()]
   public class PersonExtensionsTest
   {


      private TestContext testContextInstance;

      /// <summary>
      ///Gets or sets the test context which provides
      ///information about and functionality for the current test run.
      ///</summary>
      public TestContext TestContext
      {
         get
         {
            return testContextInstance;
         }
         set
         {
            testContextInstance = value;
         }
      }

      #region Additional test attributes
  // 
  //You can use the following additional attributes as you write your tests:
  //
  //Use ClassInitialize to run code before running the first test in the class
  //[ClassInitialize()]
  //public static void MyClassInitialize(TestContext testContext)
  //{
  //}
  //
  //Use ClassCleanup to run code after all tests in a class have run
  //[ClassCleanup()]
  //public static void MyClassCleanup()
  //{
  //}
  //
  //Use TestInitialize to run code before running each test
  //[TestInitialize()]
  //public void MyTestInitialize()
  //{
  //}
  //
  //Use TestCleanup to run code after each test has run
  //[TestCleanup()]
  //public void MyTestCleanup()
  //{
  //}
  //
  #endregion


      /// <summary>
      ///A test for Rename
      ///</summary>
      [TestMethod()]
      public void RenameTest()
      {
         Person person = new Person(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
         string newName = string.Empty; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
         PersonExtensions.Rename(person, newName); // this could also be written as person.Rename(newName);
         Assert.AreEqual(person.Name, string.Empty);
      }
   }
}
```

The test passes.

Comment: I cannot create a `Person`, only a `PersonAccessor`. Likewise, I cannot access `PersonExtensions` directly, instead I have to use `PersonExtensions_Accessor`.

Comment: @ryyst I've used the generate test feature of Visual Studio 2010, and it produced a test that throws a null-ref.  I edited my answer to include a passing test.

Comment: @ryyst what are the differences between declarations of Person and PersonAccessor in your code?  What are the namespaces and what are the access specifiers? (try to use reflector or object browser for this)